# How to match the same character at the beginning and at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

given these strings:

```
a
b
ab
ba
bab
aba
abab
babab
asdgasdgsdgasa
```

I want the following output:
true
true
false
false
true
true
false
true
true

I have this regex `^([ab])(?:.*?\1)?$`

It matches well in this debugger: https://regex101.com/
However it doesn't match anything in this debugger: https://regexr.com/

Why is that?

Also why this gives true:

```
console.log(/^([ab])(?:.*?\1)?$/.test('aba'))
true
```

While the following gives false?

```
var re = new RegExp("^([ab])(?:.*?\1)?$");

re.test("aba");
false
```

My question is not to provide new ways or new regexps that match those strings. I just want to:
1) understand why there are such differences between regex debuggers
2) If the regex I gave is good to match such strings
3) Why the first console log matches, while the second does not and what should I change in order to make it work with `re.test`

Comment: Do you really need a regex, can't you just do it directly like `str[0] === str[str.length - 1]`?

Comment: https://regexr.com/ doesn't add the `/m` multiline flag by default, your discrepancy could be because of that

Comment: They both work. regex101 has /m default and the other not. 

regexr.com/4oooq

Answer (score 3):

1. The first regex debugger has the multiline flag enabled by default; the second does not. If you enable the multiline (`m`) flag in the second one, it will work just like in the first.
2. As [ibrahim mahrir pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839572/how-to-match-the-same-character-at-the-beginning-and-at-the-end-of-a-string#comment103953455_58839572), you don't really need to use regex. You can just use `str[0] === str[str.length - 1]`.
3. In `var re = new RegExp("^([ab])(?:.*?\1)?$");`, you need to escape the backslash: `"^([ab])(?:.*?\\1)?$"`